# How do you access bookmark in your .pdf, while executing PDF from C# form?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, pdf

I created a bookstore form in C# that opens my programming books. I would like to take it further and have it perform an if statement that opens the .pdf at first bookmark if available, otherwise opens like normal. Is this possible. Here is an example of my code that accesses the PDF. This code just opens the file.

```
if (lblselected.Text == "C# Selected, Pick Your Book" && cboPDF.Text != "Pick your C# Book")
        {
            string w = System.IO.Path.Combine(@"C:\Users\Shane\Desktop\PDFBooks\C#", cboPDF.SelectedItem.ToString());
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(w);

        }
```

I would like to have a few books bookmarked, making this essentially a useful tool rather than just a book picker. This next set of code, populates combo box with selected subject/folder i.e. C#, Java, C++ and so on.

```
private void btnCSharp_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        cboPDF.Text = "Pick your C# Book";
        cboPDF.Items.Clear();
        lblselected.Text = "C# Selected, Pick Your Book";
        Directory.CreateDirectory(@"C:\Users\Shane\Desktop\PDFBooks\C#");
        DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Users\Shane\Desktop\PDFBooks\C#");
        FileInfo[] files = dir.GetFiles("*.pdf");
        foreach (FileInfo file in files)
        {
            cboPDF.Items.Add(file);
        }            
    }
```

Comment: What PDF reader do you use? Does it have command-line arguments to open on the first bookmark?

Comment: I am using Adobe as default, but was hoping to have something more universal. I also can use page number or Chapter as well. I am more or less trying to understand how accessing .pdf internally works for further exploring of ideas, so not set on bookmark.

Comment: I was able to make it work using Process.StartInfo Property. Had to change code around and add a namespace. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.startinfo.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.startinfo.aspx I ended up having to add execute file to arguments, a new namespace and change code to suit the Process.StartInfo Property.

Comment: Note for those who might use this as reference: I did not get an exact bookmark match, just a page number.